# Java - Passing value to MyOwnClass throe "="

Tags: java, operators, operator-overloading

Can I pass a value to my own String-like class like this:
MyClass mc = "String";
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible as Java does not support operator overloading.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass {

    private String str;

    public MyClass(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass("This is the string");
    }
}
```

Make sense?